# Appending Class Objects to a List

Tags: python, oop

I have some code that does some manipulation of classes. The details aren't terribly important. headerDict is a dictionary that contains lists of objects from the class NodeCluster. Node1 and Node2 are objects from the class NodeCluster. .header is an attribute of the NodeCluster class. What I want to do is iterate over the class objects in the node2 entry of headerDict, change their header attributes, and -- here's the problem part -- append each class object to a list in node1's headerDict. Here's a code snippet:

```
if len(headerDict[node1.header]) >= len(headerDict[node2.header]):
        for node in headerDict[node2.header]:
            node.k = node.k - 1
            node.header = node1.header
            headerDict[node1].append(node)
```

However, when I try to perform the append operation, I get this error:

```
KeyError: <__main__.NodeCluster instance at 0x10047b050>
```

What gives?

Comment: A guess, since I can't fully picture your data, but perhaps `headerDict[node1.header].append(node)` as the last line instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the following will fix it:

```
        headerDict[node1.header].append(node)
                        ^^^^^^^
```

since everywhere else you're using `.header` to index into `headerDict`.